# Remove Duplicates From Sorted Array Logic Throwing Exception For Correct Answer in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I answered a LeetCode question by the name of 'Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array' in two similar languages to prepare for different interviews. My Java solution was marked as correct, but the C# solution throws a Runtime Error with the message `Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`

My correct solution in Java is as follows:

```
public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
    
        int pointer1 = 0;
        
        for (int pointer2 = 1; pointer2 < nums.length; pointer2++) {
            if (nums[pointer1] != nums[pointer2]) {
                pointer1++;
                nums[pointer1] = nums[pointer2];
            }
        }
        
        return pointer1 + 1;
    }
```

My incorrect solution in C# is as follows:

```
public int RemoveDuplicates(int[] nums)
        {
            int pointer1 = 0;

            for (int pointer2 = 1; pointer2 < nums.Length; pointer2++)
            {
                if (nums[pointer1] != nums[pointer2])
                {
                    pointer1++;
                    nums[pointer1] = nums[pointer2];
                }
            }

            return pointer1 + 1;
        }
```

The requirement was to do this in-place, so I avoided using extra memory. I'm having trouble understanding why length was out of bounds for the array when I specified the length within the loop's scope. Also this error is only thrown when attempting the C# solution. I'm working to get better at C# and would like to know what the issue with my implementation is. Thank you for any and all feedback.

Comment: Are you sure you posted your code exactly?  I don't see any out-of-bounds issues there.  Perhaps whatever called that method is what's throwing the exception?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue.

Comment: It works for me. Check your  input  "nums" array has data.

Comment: I don't think it's your code that's throwing, the only OutOfRange exception yours could throw would be just "index out of bounds", not "offset and length". Whatever calls your method throws. Maybe try checking if an empty array (Length == 0) or null were passed as argument and return 0 or -1 if that's the case?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN Thank you for your answer. You were correct, it seems like the LeetCode question needed an edge case for an empty array argument. It also doesn't say what they want returned when the array is empty. I initially returned -1, but negative numbers weren't allowed. So I returned 0 and it passed. Feel free to answer the question with your comment and I'll mark it as the solution. I think others will find it useful.  if (nums.Length == 0) { return 0; } is the correct check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not your code that's throwing, since the only OutOfRange exception you would get from it would be "Index out of bounds", not "Offset and length out of bounds". Whatever calls your code throws.

It probably tries to run your method on an empty array or a null, try returning 0 or -1 when `nums.Length == 0` or `nums == null`.

(From comments: yep, it expected 0 when an empty array was passed as argument. The check needed was:

```
if (nums.Length == 0)
    return 0;
```

).